# Some JavaScript will not load on WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have been having a issues troubleshooting a problem with a JavaScript accordion menu on my WordPress site. When clicking the accordion button, it will not reveal the content hidden beneath it. I have tried many solutions, which either did not work or were over my head. I am a beginner and this is probably a simple fix but I've been struggling with this problem for days. Here is my code:

JavaScript:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
        to highlight the button that controls the panel */
        this.classList.toggle("active");

        /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
```

CSS:

```
/* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */
.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
.active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */
.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

According to FireFox, the offending piece of code is `if (panel.style.display === "block") {`, which throws a `TypeError: panel is null` exception. I have tested my page with `alert('hi');`, which works fine, so I think JavaScript is loading.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can also see the html structure

Comment: Sorry about that. Just posted it above.

Comment: Most likely `this.nextElementSibling` does not return the panel but something else (impossible to tell without the HTML). Test for that. I am a newbie at webdevelopment myself and found https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/ to be helpful in setting up accordions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Arno, I think you're right about `this.nextElementSibling`. I'm a newbie too and this is my first project, I have only basic of this HTML, CSS and JS, so I am very ignorant of how this stuff works. I wanted to be minimal so I only posted a piece of the HTML. If it helps, here is a [link](https://pastebin.com/embed_js/3YZQVsbA) to my source.

Answer (score 0):

I Added your code to a jsfiddle and it seems to be working fine, both buttons reveal the hidden content.

https://jsfiddle.net/pnuyLhbq/1/

So your current code is fine if you add another accordion button

```
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```